# resque workers exit shortly after start with no output

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, resque, god

I am trying to get resque working in production. I have the following god file:

```
rails_env   = ENV['RAILS_ENV']  || "production"
rails_root  = ENV['RAILS_ROOT'] || "/home/rails/current"
num_workers = rails_env == 'production' ? 5 : 2

num_workers.times do |num|
  God.watch do |w|
    w.dir      = "#{rails_root}"
    w.name     = "resque-#{num}"
    w.group    = 'resque'
    w.interval = 30.seconds
    w.env      = {"QUEUE"=>"add_feed,update_all,update_feed", "RAILS_ENV"=>rails_env}
    w.start    = "rake -f #{rails_root}/Rakefile environment resque:work"
    w.log      = "#{rails_root}/log/#{w.name}.log"

    w.uid = 'rails'
    w.gid = 'rails'

    # restart if memory gets too high
    w.transition(:up, :restart) do |on|
      on.condition(:memory_usage) do |c|
        c.above = 350.megabytes
        c.times = 2
      end
    end

    # determine the state on startup
    w.transition(:init, { true => :up, false => :start }) do |on|
      on.condition(:process_running) do |c|
        c.running = true
      end
    end

    # determine when process has finished starting
    w.transition([:start, :restart], :up) do |on|
      on.condition(:process_running) do |c|
        c.running = true
        c.interval = 5.seconds
      end

      # failsafe
      on.condition(:tries) do |c|
        c.times = 5
        c.transition = :start
        c.interval = 5.seconds
      end
    end

    # start if process is not running
    w.transition(:up, :start) do |on|
      on.condition(:process_running) do |c|
        c.running = false
      end
    end
  end
end
```

But when I try to run god, I get the following output:

```
root@pocketrss:~# god -c /home/rails/current/config/resque.god -D
I [2014-02-04 19:33:23]  INFO: Loading /home/rails/current/config/resque.god
I [2014-02-04 19:33:23]  INFO: Syslog enabled.
I [2014-02-04 19:33:23]  INFO: Using pid file directory: /var/run/god
I [2014-02-04 19:33:24]  INFO: Started on drbunix:///tmp/god.17165.sock
I [2014-02-04 19:33:24]  INFO: resque-0 move 'unmonitored' to 'init'
I [2014-02-04 19:33:24]  INFO: resque-1 move 'unmonitored' to 'init'
I [2014-02-04 19:33:24]  INFO: resque-2 move 'unmonitored' to 'init'
I [2014-02-04 19:33:24]  INFO: resque-3 move 'unmonitored' to 'init'
I [2014-02-04 19:33:24]  INFO: resque-4 move 'unmonitored' to 'init'
I [2014-02-04 19:33:24]  INFO: resque-4 moved 'unmonitored' to 'init'
I [2014-02-04 19:33:24]  INFO: resque-3 moved 'unmonitored' to 'init'
I [2014-02-04 19:33:24]  INFO: resque-2 moved 'unmonitored' to 'init'
I [2014-02-04 19:33:24]  INFO: resque-1 moved 'unmonitored' to 'init'
I [2014-02-04 19:33:24]  INFO: resque-0 moved 'unmonitored' to 'init'
I [2014-02-04 19:33:24]  INFO: resque-0 [trigger] process is not running (ProcessRunning)
I [2014-02-04 19:33:24]  INFO: resque-0 move 'init' to 'start'
I [2014-02-04 19:33:24]  INFO: resque-0 start: rake -f /home/rails/current/Rakefile environment resque:work
I [2014-02-04 19:33:24]  INFO: resque-2 [trigger] process is running (ProcessRunning)
I [2014-02-04 19:33:24]  INFO: resque-1 [trigger] process is not running (ProcessRunning)
I [2014-02-04 19:33:24]  INFO: resque-3 [trigger] process is running (ProcessRunning)
I [2014-02-04 19:33:24]  INFO: resque-4 [trigger] process is not running (ProcessRunning)
I [2014-02-04 19:33:24]  INFO: resque-1 move 'init' to 'start'
I [2014-02-04 19:33:24]  INFO: resque-4 move 'init' to 'start'
I [2014-02-04 19:33:24]  INFO: resque-3 move 'init' to 'up'
I [2014-02-04 19:33:24]  INFO: resque-4 start: rake -f /home/rails/current/Rakefile environment resque:work
I [2014-02-04 19:33:24]  INFO: resque-2 move 'init' to 'up'
I [2014-02-04 19:33:24]  INFO: resque-3 moved 'init' to 'up'
I [2014-02-04 19:33:24]  INFO: resque-1 start: rake -f /home/rails/current/Rakefile environment resque:work
I [2014-02-04 19:33:24]  INFO: resque-2 moved 'init' to 'up'
I [2014-02-04 19:33:25]  INFO: resque-0 moved 'init' to 'start'
I [2014-02-04 19:33:25]  INFO: resque-0 [trigger] process is running (ProcessRunning)
I [2014-02-04 19:33:25]  INFO: resque-0 move 'start' to 'up'
I [2014-02-04 19:33:25]  INFO: resque-0 moved 'start' to 'up'
I [2014-02-04 19:33:25]  INFO: resque-4 moved 'init' to 'start'
I [2014-02-04 19:33:25]  INFO: resque-4 [trigger] process is running (ProcessRunning)
I [2014-02-04 19:33:25]  INFO: resque-4 move 'start' to 'up'
I [2014-02-04 19:33:25]  INFO: resque-4 moved 'start' to 'up'
I [2014-02-04 19:33:25]  INFO: resque-1 moved 'init' to 'start'
I [2014-02-04 19:33:25]  INFO: resque-1 [trigger] process is running (ProcessRunning)
I [2014-02-04 19:33:25]  INFO: resque-1 move 'start' to 'up'
I [2014-02-04 19:33:25]  INFO: resque-1 moved 'start' to 'up'
I [2014-02-04 19:33:54]  INFO: resque-3 [trigger] process is not running (ProcessRunning)
I [2014-02-04 19:33:54]  INFO: resque-3 move 'up' to 'start'
I [2014-02-04 19:33:54]  INFO: resque-3 start: rake -f /home/rails/current/Rakefile environment resque:work
I [2014-02-04 19:33:54]  INFO: resque-2 [trigger] process is not running (ProcessRunning)
I [2014-02-04 19:33:54]  INFO: resque-2 move 'up' to 'start'
I [2014-02-04 19:33:54]  INFO: resque-2 start: rake -f /home/rails/current/Rakefile environment resque:work
I [2014-02-04 19:33:54]  INFO: resque-3 moved 'up' to 'start'
I [2014-02-04 19:33:54]  INFO: resque-3 [trigger] process is running (ProcessRunning)
I [2014-02-04 19:33:54]  INFO: resque-3 move 'start' to 'up'
I [2014-02-04 19:33:54]  INFO: resque-3 moved 'start' to 'up'
I [2014-02-04 19:33:54]  INFO: resque-2 moved 'up' to 'start'
I [2014-02-04 19:33:54]  INFO: resque-2 [trigger] process is running (ProcessRunning)
I [2014-02-04 19:33:54]  INFO: resque-2 move 'start' to 'up'
I [2014-02-04 19:33:54]  INFO: resque-2 moved 'start' to 'up'
I [2014-02-04 19:33:55]  INFO: resque-0 [trigger] process is not running (ProcessRunning)
I [2014-02-04 19:33:55]  INFO: resque-0 move 'up' to 'start'
I [2014-02-04 19:33:55]  INFO: resque-0 start: rake -f /home/rails/current/Rakefile environment resque:work
I [2014-02-04 19:33:55]  INFO: resque-4 [trigger] process is not running (ProcessRunning)
I [2014-02-04 19:33:55]  INFO: resque-4 move 'up' to 'start'
I [2014-02-04 19:33:55]  INFO: resque-4 start: rake -f /home/rails/current/Rakefile environment resque:work
I [2014-02-04 19:33:55]  INFO: resque-1 [trigger] process is not running (ProcessRunning)
I [2014-02-04 19:33:55]  INFO: resque-1 move 'up' to 'start'
I [2014-02-04 19:33:55]  INFO: resque-1 start: rake -f /home/rails/current/Rakefile environment resque:work
I [2014-02-04 19:33:55]  INFO: resque-4 moved 'up' to 'start'
I [2014-02-04 19:33:55]  INFO: resque-4 [trigger] process is running (ProcessRunning)
I [2014-02-04 19:33:55]  INFO: resque-4 move 'start' to 'up'
I [2014-02-04 19:33:55]  INFO: resque-4 moved 'start' to 'up'
I [2014-02-04 19:33:55]  INFO: resque-0 moved 'up' to 'start'
I [2014-02-04 19:33:55]  INFO: resque-0 [trigger] process is running (ProcessRunning)
I [2014-02-04 19:33:55]  INFO: resque-0 move 'start' to 'up'
I [2014-02-04 19:33:55]  INFO: resque-0 moved 'start' to 'up'
I [2014-02-04 19:33:55]  INFO: resque-1 moved 'up' to 'start'
I [2014-02-04 19:33:55]  INFO: resque-1 [trigger] process is running (ProcessRunning)
I [2014-02-04 19:33:55]  INFO: resque-1 move 'start' to 'up'
I [2014-02-04 19:33:55]  INFO: resque-1 moved 'start' to ‘up'
```

Basically, resque is exiting every few seconds. I have no log output, no errors, nothing.

Comment: Did you check the memory at the time when the resque are get started it could be quite possible that the resque process would surpass 350MB limit of your and restart of the process would be happening because of that

Answer (score 1):

I had this same problem in my development environment, running

```
QUEUE=* bundle exec rake resque:work
```

would just exit to command line. I had to run with VVERBOSE=1 to figure what was going on. for me I got the following error:

```
Failed to start worker : #<NoMethodError: undefined method `auto_flushing=' for #<ActiveSupport::Logger:0x00000108908ab8>>
```

and it turns out that in the project we had

```
Resque.before_first_fork = Proc.new { Rails.logger.auto_flushing = 1 }
```

in our resque.rake file, in the resque:setup task.